# QuickFIX - Receive and send orders from different algorithms (sources)

Tags: java, rest, quickfix, fix-protocol, algorithmic-trading

I built a FIX Initiator Application using the QuickFIX/J library to send orders to my broker. If you don't know what is a FIX Application, consider that my program is an application that sends message to a server through TCP connection.

To get and send the orders created by multiple algorithms I have a Directory Watcher (WatchService) that watches for modifications on a local directory that is synchronized with a S3 bucket using AWS Cli.

This approach works well, except for the fact that I have to wait about 6-8 seconds before the file is on my local directory, so I can parse it to fix orders and send to broker's FIX app. **I really would like to decrease this delay between the order creation and the moment when it is send to the broker.**

**What are the possible solutions that I'd tought:**

**1)** *Reading directly from S3 bucket without using AWS CLI*

**2)** *Opening different FIX sessions for each different algorithm*

**3)** *Instead of reading from a bucket, peaking a database (MySQL) for new orders. The algos would generate table rows instead of files*

**4)** *Having an API between my FIX application and the algorithms, so the algos can connect directly with my application.*

Solution (1) didn't improved the order receiving time because it takes about the same time to list S3 objects, get summary and filter the desired file.

Solution (2) I didn't tried, but I think it is not the best one. If I have, for example, 100 different strategies I would have to open 100 different connections and I am not sure if my broker app can handle. But I may be wrong.

Solution (3) I also didn't tried.

Solution (4) is what I believe that is ideal, but I don't know how to implement. I tried to create an REST API, but I don't know if it is conceptually correct. Supposing that my FIX application is currently connected to the broker's server, my idea was to (i) create a new webapp to create a REST API (ii) receive order info through a API, (iii) find the current alive session and (iv) send order to broker server using the current session. Unfortunately, I was not able to find the current session by ID using the following on a different of the class that is running the FIX application:

```
SessionID sessionID = new SessionID("FIX.4.4", "CLIENT1", "FixServer");
    Session session = Session.lookupSession(sessionID);
```

What I would like to hear from you:

- What do you think that is the best solution to send FIX orders created by multiple sources?

  - If I want to create an API to connect 2 different applications, what are the steps that I can follow?

I am sorry if I was a bit confuse. Let me know if you need further clarification.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **Q** : *What do you think that is the best solution to send FIX orders created by multiple sources?*

Definitely the **4)** -i.e.- consolidate your multiple sources of decisions and interface the Broker-side FIX Protocol Gateway from a single point.

**Reasons:**
- isolation of concerns in design/implementation/operations
- single point of authentication/latency-motivated colocation for FIX Protocol channel
- minimised costs of FIX Protocol Gateway acceptance-testing (without this Tier-1 market participants will not let you run business with, so expenses on FIX Protocol E2E-mutual-cooperation compliance-testing do matter - both costs-wise and time-wise )

> **Q** : *what are the steps that I can follow?*

Follow you own use-case, that defines all the MVP-features that need to be ready for going into testing.

Do not try to generalise your needs into any "new-Next-Gen-API", your trading is all about latency+trading, so rather specialise on the MVP-definition and do not design/implement anything beyond an MVP with minimum latency (overhead) on a point to point basis. Using stable professional frameworks, like [**nanomsg** or **ZeroMQ**](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=user%3A3666197%20real-time), may avoid spending a bit of time on reinventing any already invented wheels for low-latency trading messaging/signaling tools. Using REST is rather an anti-pattern in the 3rd millenium low-latency motivated high performance distributed computing eco-system for trading.

Comment: Thank you very much. You answer was really useful!